# How do I get the content of "shoppingList" to print using the function PrintNodeData()?

Tags: c++, linked-list

> Given a ListItem
> class, complete main() using the built-in list type to create a linked list called shoppingList. The program should read items from input (ending with -1), adding each item to shoppingList, and output each item in shoppingList using the PrintNodeData() function.
>
> Ex. If the input is:
> `milk bread eggs waffles cereal -1`
>
> the output is:
> `milk bread eggs waffles cereal`

My code:

```
#include "ListItem.h"
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
// TODO: Declare a list called shoppingList of type ListItem
list<ListItem>shoppingList;

string item;

// TODO: Read inputs (items) and add them to the shoppingList list
// Read inputs until a -1 is input
do
{
getline(cin, item);
if(item[item.length()-1] == -1)
break;
else
shoppingList.push_back(ListItem(item));
}
while (true);
// TODO: Print the shoppingList list using the PrintNodeData() function
void PrintNodeData();
return 0;
}
```

**ListItem.h**

```
#ifndef LISTITEMH
#define LISTITEMH

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class ListItem {
public:
ListItem();

ListItem(string itemInit);

// Print this node
void PrintNodeData();

private:
string item;
};

#endif
```

**ListItem.cpp**

```
#include "ListItem.h"
#include <iostream>

ListItem::ListItem() {
item = "";
}

ListItem::ListItem(string itemInit) {
item = itemInit;
}

// Print this node
void ListItem::PrintNodeData() {
cout << item << endl;
```

I've tried looping through to print each value by using:

```
for( int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(shoppingList.size()); i++)
shoppingList[i].PrintNodeData;
```

Comment: Please format your code so it is legible.  If what you tried didn't work, explain what specific problem(s) you had with it.

Comment: There seem to be multiple errors in the code above, but it's very hard to read. Please fix the formatting.

Comment: Regarding the code you tried `for( int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(shoppingList.size()); i++) shoppingList[i].PrintNodeData;` should be `for( int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(shoppingList.size()); i++) shoppingList[i].PrintNodeData();` Notice the extra `()` at the end. But I doubt that is your only problem, as I said, multiple errors.

Comment: Your question is rather lacking in text. In fact, ignoring the assignment that was given to you, there is **one** sentence outside the code. This is a very bad sign. Please see [ask] and [mre]. *Ideas for improvement **for this question**: explain why you thought your code would work, hardcode data (don't require input from the user), show your expected and actual output, and focus your code on your question, not on your assignment (there should be no "to do"s for this question -- those are for your assignment).*

Answer (score 0):

Just utilize C++'s range for loop to traverse the list:

```cpp
for(auto& listItem : shoppingList)
{
    if(listItem.item != "-1")
    {
        item.PrintNodeData();
    }
}
```

P.S since you are a student (this is clearly an assignment) It might be worth to tell you to **drop the `using namespace std` statement**, it is a terribly bad practice that might lead to function aliasing once your projects get more complex, just get the habit to prefix your standard library calls with `std::` now that you are learning and you'll be safer